# pygame with infinitely scrolling background - handling of sprites movement

Tags: python, object-oriented, pygame

In my current project I try to implement the basic game logic of the game "Vampire Survival" (Little impression of the first level can be seen in this video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSi4YwPrdFE)).

**Question**
I want to know if regarding to the concepts of OOP I should restructure my code from the beginning or continue building on it like I started.

The whole structure looks like this at the moment:

```
project
│   
└───main.py
│      - main()
│ 
└───enemy.py
│      class Enemy(Sprite):
│       - draw()
│       - update()
│ 
└───player.py
│      class Player(Sprite):
│       - draw()
│       - shoot()
│
└───bullet.py
│      class Bullet(Sprite):
│       - update()
│
└───functions.py
       - get_df_from_json()
       - convert_framelist_to_image_objects()
       - create_player()
       - create_enemy()
       - create_bullet()
       - spawn_enemies()
       - scroll_background()
       - levels_create_enemies()
       - get_direction()
```

**Functionality**
I have 3 classes at the moment, `Player`, `Enemy` and `Bullet`.

There is an infinitely field, where the main character is always in the middle of the screen, if he moves, the background is moving while him staying in the center.
I wrote a function `scroll_background()` that does that for me, together with a infinity background image I have no "borders".

The enemies spawn in random coordinates outside of the screen. The enemies will always move towards the middle of the screen (= always to the player). The calculation for that is made in `draw()` in the Enemy Sprite class. The amount of the enemies and which enemy should be time related and level related). I have all Players and Enemies of the original game as spritesheet with a big json file to access them. For the moment to get progress done, I just hardcoded some list of the Player and Enemy I want to keep it simple.

Every few seconds the player shoots a bullet (without a key event) and the bullet (starting at the middle of the screen) fires in the direction where the player is currently moving (8 directions). At the moment the collision with the enemies isn't implemented.

In the `update()` function of the Enemy Sprite class the calculation and movement relativ to the player is done: (it is called in every handling of the key press events of the 4 directions (left, right, top, bottom), signs and ax needed to call it for every direction.

For the moment I don't focus on how Enemies, Player and Bullets are created (I just wanted it to work for the basics) and also the way the so called "levels" are implemented. It's all about the way I handle all movements on the playground relative to the infinite scrolling background.

I get the feeling the way I structured my code will bite me in the future. The handling of different movements will be done at too many different places. Also it is very vulnerable to bugs or mistakes with all the relative coordinates. Every single new item, enemy, weapon, shield and anything else I will implement needs to be handled relatively to the middle of the screen (while keeping track of the real current x and y position of the player).

I don't know how else it is possible to have this infinite playfield with a static player in the mid else than I did it. The code gets messier the more I try to add and I don't know how to keep my code clean and more adjustable.
How should I handle all the other movements, any suggestions for me? Any ideas how to structure my code differently? The whole thing is (beside it's fun) to get a better understanding of OOP, I feel like I miss something here and don't take the advantages of it.

My code:

`player.py`:

```
import pygame

from bullet import Bullet

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,
                 x: int,
                 y: int,
                 images: list,
                 sheet: pygame.Surface,
                 screen: pygame.Surface):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.moving_count = 0
        self.spritesheet = sheet
        self.images = images
        self.standing = self.images[0]
        self.moving = self.images[1:]
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.standing.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))
        self.screen = screen

    def draw(self, moving: bool):

        # choosing the animation images from list
        rate = 20
        num_images = len(self.moving)
        animation_image_speed = num_images * rate
        img_index = self.moving_count//rate

        if self.moving_count + 1 >= animation_image_speed:
            self.moving_count = 0

        if moving:
            self.screen.blit(self.moving[img_index],
                             self.screen.get_rect().center)
            self.moving_count += 1
        else:
            self.screen.blit(self.standing, self.screen.get_rect().center)

        self.rect.center = self.screen.get_rect().center

    def shoot(self, bullet_group, image, bull_dx, bull_dy):
        bull = Bullet((self.rect.centerx + (0.6 *
                      self.rect.size[0]), self.rect.centery), image, bull_dx, bull_dy)
        bullet_group.add(bull)
        # print(bull.time)
        return bull
```

`enemy.py`:

```
import math
from typing import Tuple

import pygame

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,
                 images: list,
                 sheet: pygame.Surface,
                 spawn_coords: Tuple[int, int],
                 speed_factor: float,
                 field_moving_speed: int,
                ):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.moving_count = 0
        self.field_moving_speed = -field_moving_speed
        self.speed_factor = speed_factor
        self.spritesheet = sheet
        self.images = images
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.x, self.y = spawn_coords
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))

    def draw(self, win: pygame.Surface):
        # MOVE towards player:
        target_x, target_y = win.get_rect().center
        radians = math.atan2(target_y - self.y, target_x - self.x)
        dx = self.speed_factor * math.cos(radians)
        dy = self.speed_factor * math.sin(radians)
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
        
        #DRAW the enemy on the screen:
        rate = 20
        num_images = len(self.images)
        animation_image_speed = num_images * rate
        
        if self.moving_count + 1 >= animation_image_speed:
            self.moving_count = 0
        win.blit(self.images[self.moving_count//rate],(self.x, self.y))
        self.moving_count += 1

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))
    
    def update(self,sign=1, ax='x'):
        if ax=='x':
            self.x += (sign * self.field_moving_speed)
        else: 
            self.y += (sign * self.field_moving_speed)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))
```

`bullet.py`:

```
import time
from typing import Tuple
import pygame

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, xy: Tuple[int, int], image: pygame.Surface, bull_dx: float,  bull_dy: float) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.x, self.y = xy
        self.speed = 6
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = xy
        self.time = time.time()
        self.dx = bull_dx
        self.dy = bull_dy

    def update(self):
        bullet_alive = time.time() - self.time
        if bullet_alive >= 4:
            self.kill()

        self.x += int(self.speed * self.dx)
        self.y += int(self.speed * self.dy)
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
```

`functions.py`:

```
import json
import math
import os
import random
from typing import Tuple

import pandas as pd
import pygame

from enemy import Enemy


def get_df_frames_from_json(folder: str, file: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Input: path, file
    Return: DataFrame with information about the positions of each image in the big image
    """
    with open(os.path.join(folder, file)) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    df = pd.json_normalize(data['textures'][0]['frames'])
    df = df.drop(df.columns[1:9],axis=1)
    df['char'] = df['filename'].str.split('.',expand=True)[0]
    
    return df


def convert_framelist_to_image_objects(list_of_lists: list, spritesheet: pygame.image) -> list:
    """
    Input: list of frame information
    Return: list of Image Objects
    """
    image_list = []
    for ls in list_of_lists:
        x, y, w, h = ls
        image = pygame.Surface((w, h)).convert_alpha()
        image.blit(spritesheet, (0, 0), (x, y, w, h))
        #image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (w * scale, h * scale))
        image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        image_list.append(image)
    return image_list


def create_player(
    folder: str,
    file: str,
    name: str,
    spritesheet_characters: pygame.Surface
) -> list:
    """
    from spreadsheet and its json data to list of images of one character 
    Returns:
        list of lists with frame positions for all images with the searched character name
    """
    # load json, convert to df and do some changes
    df = get_df_frames_from_json(folder, file)
    list_of_lists = (df[df['char'].str.startswith(name)]
                     .filter(like='frame')
                     .drop_duplicates(subset=['frame.x', 'frame.y', 'frame.w', 'frame.h'])
                     .values.tolist())
    player_image_list = convert_framelist_to_image_objects(
        list_of_lists, spritesheet_characters)

    return player_image_list


def create_enemy(
    folder: str,
    file: str,
    name: list,
    spritesheet_enemies: pygame.Surface,
) -> list:

    df = get_df_frames_from_json(folder, file)
    list_of_lists = (df[df['filename'].isin(name)]
                     .filter(like='frame')
                     .drop_duplicates(subset=['frame.x', 'frame.y', 'frame.w', 'frame.h'])
                     .values.tolist())
    enemy_image_list = convert_framelist_to_image_objects(
        list_of_lists, spritesheet_enemies)

    return enemy_image_list


def create_bullet(
    folder: str,
    file: str,
    name: list,
    spritesheet_weapons: pygame.Surface,
) -> list:

    df = get_df_frames_from_json(folder, file)

    list_of_lists = (df[df['filename'].isin(name)]
                     .filter(like='frame')
                     .drop_duplicates(subset=['frame.x', 'frame.y', 'frame.w', 'frame.h'])
                     .values.tolist())
    bullet_image_list = convert_framelist_to_image_objects(
        list_of_lists, spritesheet_weapons)

    return bullet_image_list

def spawn_enemies() -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Enemies always spawn from outside of the screen in a given range so they don't appear all together at the same time
    return: Tuple with x and y coordinates of Enemies
    """
    spawn_x = random.choice(
        [random.randint(-650, -150), random.randint(850, 1350)])
    spawn_y = random.choice(
        [random.randint(-660, -150), random.randint(850, 1350)])

    return spawn_x, spawn_y


def scroll_background(screen: pygame.Surface, bkgd: pygame.Surface, x: int, y: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Keep track of players real x and y coordinates while background is moving to keep player always in mid
    return: Tuple with x and y coordinates of Player
    """

    xOff = (0 - x % bkgd.get_rect().width)
    yOff = (0 - y % bkgd.get_rect().height)

    screen.blit(bkgd, [xOff, yOff])
    screen.blit(bkgd, [xOff + bkgd.get_rect().width, yOff])
    screen.blit(bkgd, [xOff, yOff + bkgd.get_rect().height])
    screen.blit(bkgd, [xOff + bkgd.get_rect().width, yOff + bkgd.get_rect().height])
    
    return x,y


def levels_create_enemies(level, total_time_game, dic, enemy_group, lst_names, all_enemies, moving_speed):
    """
    creates enemies after given amount of time
    Each level spawn different enemies
    Informations of the different enemies are stored in the dictionary "dic"
    
    Returns: Tuple with level and enemy_group (Sprites)
    """
    if (level == 0 and total_time_game <= 30):
        for _ in range(100):
            enemy = Enemy(dic[lst_names[3]][0], all_enemies, spawn_enemies(
            ), dic[lst_names[3]][1], moving_speed)
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
        level += 1
    elif (level == 1 and 30 < total_time_game <= 60):
        for _ in range(100):
            enemy = Enemy(dic[lst_names[1]][0], all_enemies, spawn_enemies(
            ), dic[lst_names[1]][1], moving_speed)
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
        level += 1
    elif (level == 2 and 60 < total_time_game <= 90):
        for _ in range(100):
            enemy = Enemy(dic[lst_names[2]][0], all_enemies, spawn_enemies(
            ), dic[lst_names[2]][1], moving_speed)
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
        level += 1
    elif (level == 3 and 90 < total_time_game <= 120):
        for _ in range(100):
            enemy = Enemy(dic[lst_names[3]][0], all_enemies, spawn_enemies(
            ), dic[lst_names[3]][1], moving_speed)
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
        level += 1

    return level, enemy_group


def get_direction(keys: list) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    """
    input: current key presses
    return: Tuple with x,y for 8 directions each 45°
    """
    diag = math.cos(math.radians(45))
    if not any(list(keys)):
        return 1, 0  # where to shoot when not moving
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            return -diag, -diag
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            return -diag, diag
        else:
            return -1, 0
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            return diag, -diag
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            return diag, diag
        else:
            return 1, 0
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        return 0, -1
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        return 0, 1
```

`main.py`:

````
import os
import time

import pygame

from functions import (create_bullet, create_enemy, create_player,
                       get_direction, levels_create_enemies, scroll_background)
from player import Player


def main():
    
    #Setup pygame
    pygame.init()
    CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 700, 700
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Custom Vampire_Survivals')

    # path
    game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'assets', 'img')

    # load background
    BKGD = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'bg_molise.png')).convert()
    
    # load spritesheets
    all_players = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'characters.png')).convert_alpha()
    all_enemies = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'enemies.png')).convert_alpha()
    vfx_png = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'vfx.png')).convert_alpha()
    
    # image lists of Player
    player_image_list = create_player(
        img_folder, 
        'characters.json', 
        'Antonio', 
        all_players
        )
    
    # dictionary of image lists of Enemies
    # manually extract Enemies to keep things a little more simple
    Bat1 = ['Bat1_0.png', 'Bat1_i01.png', 'Bat1_i02.png', 'Bat1_i03.png']
    XLReaper = ['XLReaper_i01.png', 'XLReaper_i02.png', 'XLReaper_i03.png',
                'XLReaper_i04.png', 'XLReaper_i05.png', 'XLReaper_i06.png', 'XLReaper_i08.png']
    XLCount = ['XLCount2_i01.png', 'XLCount2_i02.png', 'XLCount2_i03.png',
               'XLCount2_i04.png', 'XLCount2_i05.png', 'XLCount2_i06.png']
    XLMummy = ['XLMummy_i01.png', 'XLMummy_i02.png', 'XLMummy_i03.png']
    lst_enemies = [Bat1, XLReaper, XLCount, XLMummy]
    lst_names = ['Bat1', 'XLReaper', 'XLCount', 'XLMummy']
    speed_factor = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
    enemy_dict = {}
    for name, en, speed_f in zip(lst_names, lst_enemies, speed_factor):
        enemy_image_list = create_enemy(
            img_folder, 
            'enemies.json',
            en,
            all_enemies)
        enemy_dict[name] = (enemy_image_list, speed_f)
    
    # image lists of bullets
    bullet = ['ProjectileFireball2.png']
    bull_image = create_bullet(
        img_folder,
        'vfx.json',
        bullet,
        vfx_png        
    )[0]
    
    # Initialisation
    start = time.time()
    level = 0
    bullet_counter = 0
    moving_speed = 3
    run = True
    moving = False

    # create sprite
    player = Player(0, 0, player_image_list, all_players, SCREEN)
    enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

    while run:
        
        current_time = time.time()
        total_time_game = current_time - start
        if level <= 3:
            level, enemy_group = levels_create_enemies(
                level, 
                total_time_game, 
                enemy_dict, 
                enemy_group, 
                lst_names, 
                all_enemies, 
                moving_speed)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                quit()

        player.x, player.y = scroll_background(
            SCREEN, BKGD, player.x, player.y)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if any(list(keys)):
            moving = True
        else:
            moving = False

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player.x -= moving_speed
            enemy_group.update(sign=-1)
            if len(bullet_group) > 0:
                for bull in bullet_group:
                    bull.x += moving_speed

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player.x += moving_speed
            enemy_group.update()
            if len(bullet_group) > 0:
                for bull in bullet_group:
                    bull.x -= moving_speed

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            player.y -= moving_speed
            enemy_group.update(sign=-1, ax='y')
            if len(bullet_group) > 0:
                for bull in bullet_group:
                    bull.y += moving_speed

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player.y += moving_speed
            enemy_group.update(ax='y')
            if len(bullet_group) > 0:
                for bull in bullet_group:
                    bull.y -= moving_speed

        for sprite in enemy_group.sprites():
            sprite.draw(SCREEN)

        player.draw(moving)
        bullet_counter += 1
        if bullet_counter >= FPS * 5:  # every 5 seconds
            bull_dx, bull_dy = get_direction(keys)
            player.shoot(bullet_group, bull_image, bull_dx, bull_dy)
            bullet_counter = 0

        bullet_group.update()
        bullet_group.draw(SCREEN)

        for enemy in enemy_group.sprites():
            if player.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill(enemy)

        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() 
```
````

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review community. We are quite different from the Stack Overflow community, we want to see as much code as possible so that we can provide a good review. You can post full multiple classes here at once rather than snippets from multiple classes. That would allow us to do a better code review. We don't solve specific problems on this site.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thank you for pointing that out! I will edit my question.